# MySQL regex for word boundary containing '@'

Tags: mysql, sql, regex

I'm trying to search for an example phrase: `'@test123'` using regex like:

```
SELECT (...) WHERE x RLIKE '[[:<:]]@test123[[:>:]]'
```

With no luck. Probably the word boundary selector `'[[:<:]]'` does not count '@' as a word.

How to achieve it? How to set in MySQL regex word boundary selector but with exceptions?

Comment: `@` is not a word character, so this regex will never match as `[[:<:]]` (*beginning of a word*) is a leading word boundary and expects the next char to be an alphanumeric/underscore.

Comment: remove `[[:<:]]`....

Comment: Or you might try with `RLIKE '(^|[^_[:alnum:]])@test123($|[^_[:alnum:]])'`. The point is that we do not know what word boudary is for you. How do you define a "word" for this task? What "exceptions" do you mean? That part is very unclear.

Comment: @Avinash Raj: and then what ?

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew: cool, I know that - question is how to fix it ?

Comment: Since lookarounds are not supported, I can onyl suggest something like `'([[:<:]]|[[:blank:]])@test123([[:>:]]|[[:blank:]])'`

Comment: What is the context your "words" can appear in?

Comment: I assume the keyword should start either after a word boundary, or space, but maybe I am missing some other cases. Maybe [`'(^|[[:<:]]|[[:blank:]])@test123([[:>:]]|[[:blank:]]|$)'`](https://regex101.com/r/nT8pL7/1) will work better...

Comment: Oh, yeah, perhaps, even [`'(^|[[:<:]]|[[:punct:][:blank:]])@test123([[:>:]]|[[:blank:][:punct:]]|$)'`](https://regex101.com/r/nT8pL7/2).

Comment: Still I don't think the OP wants to match `More@test123-here`.. I believe he's trying to simulate a `\B` **[demo](https://regex101.com/r/nT8pL7/3)

Comment: @user6643566 Can you test `'(^|[[:punct:]]|[[:blank:]])@test123[[:>:]]'` and let us know if it works for you?

Answer (score 1):

[MySQL 5.7 Reference Manual  /  ...  /  Regular Expressions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html):

> [[:<:]], [[:>:]]
>
> These markers stand for word boundaries. They match the beginning and
>   end of words, respectively. A word is a sequence of word characters
>   that is not preceded by or followed by word characters. A word
>   character is an alphanumeric character in the alnum class or an
>   underscore (_).

So, `@` is a word boundary, not a word character. We need to expand "word characters" class to include `@` too. The simplest way is to enumerate custom word characters directly `a-z0-9_@`:

```
SELECT * FROM
(
   SELECT '@test123'         AS x UNION ALL
   SELECT 'and @test123 too'      UNION ALL
   SELECT 'not@test123not'        UNION ALL
   SELECT 'not@test123'           UNION ALL
   SELECT '@test123not'           UNION ALL
   SELECT 'not @ test123'         UNION ALL
   SELECT 'test123'               UNION ALL 
   SELECT '@west123'
) t
WHERE x RLIKE '([^a-z0-9_@]|^)@test123([^a-z0-9_@]|$)';
```

Result:

```
x
----------------
@test123
and @test123 too
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use below expression instead:

```
'[.@.][[:<:]]test123[[:>:]]'
```

> Note: don't use non-word literals inside `[[:<:]][[:>:]]` and use `[..]` for characters.

Or (with thanks to @Y.B.)

```
'(^|.*[^a-zA-Z0-9_])[.@.][[:<:]]test123[[:>:]]'
```